# How can two clicks lead to better security in the context of, e.g., Twitter and Facebook share buttons?

Tags: web-browser

The sharing section of Jedox's [webpage](http://www.jedox.com/en/solutions/finance/) has the Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and Linkedin share options in default inactive state. You need to first click it to activate and click again to get the share window.

Hovering the inactive button it says

> Two clicks for a better data security: The first click will activate the button, the second will share your recommendation with facebook. Data is shared with third parties upon activation - see *i*.

[image]

So, how does two clicks make the security better?

Comment: (Excuse the lousy tagging couldn't think of what would be suitable here)

Comment: It's a double confirm pattern. Would really work well with the new single click to buy apple iwatches.

Comment: Was this question answered?

Comment: I am yet to understand the statement "privacy is a useful side-effect of a secure system", @rook . The term *side-effect* is troubling me.

Comment: @Bleeding Fingers The NSA is also troubled by this side-effect,  which is why they want to backdoor everything, and even collect stats from webbugs.

Answer (score 8):

This is about personal privacy for users of the site.

Like buttons are advanced [web beacons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug).  Its more than just a simple image,  but JavaScript that identifies if you are a logged into a social network,  and tracks your behavior over a long period of time. Facebook collects this information for targeted advertising.

In this security system, if you don't need the like button,  then don't load that JavaScript widget.  If you want to click like, then you need to load the specific JavaScript widget that you need.

Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313037/how-do-google-1-widgets-break-out-of-their-iframe/7313430#7313430

Comment: Isn't it more about privacy rather than security?

Comment: @Bleeding Fingers privacy is a useful side-effect of a secure system.